# Virtual directory and trailing slash

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have published two websites under the Default Web Site node in IIS:

```
> Default Web Site
    > Site1
    > Site2
```

The idea is that they should reply to the following URL:

- localhost/Site1
- localhost/Site2

The website is protected by authentication therefore the first page is the login page. The URL I get is as follows:

```
http://localhost/Site1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fSite1
```

After I put username and password the website is not able to redirect me to the home page and always land in the login page (even though the authentication is completed correctly, because if I write an URL of the website, this will work correctly).

But, if I force the starting URL to (adding a backslash at the end):

```
http://localhost/Site1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fSite1/
```

The website works properly. Moreover, the website works properly even if I publish it as a standalone website (not an application of the Default Web Site):

```
> Default Web Site
> Site1
> Site2
```

Am I missing something in my IIS configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was a known issue.
With some more research I found out it was a trailing slash problem and I worked it out using IIS URL Rewrite, as suggested [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Change the port no and try

port for both site inherrit from Default Website port no.

better practice to make each application/site on root and provide them different port.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I found out it was a problem with trailing slash, anyway thanks a lot for your help